# Spring JPA with DB2 error SqlSyntaxErrorException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

I am trying to create a Spring Boot app to read data from DB2 view

My application.properties has data source as:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://servername:port/dbname
spring.datasource.username=me
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect
```

When I run my application, it errors with error below:

**com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=me;CREATE TABLE;DSNDB04, DRIVER=4.29.24**

Based on my reading, this error means that user "me" does not have priviledge to run operation "CREATE TABLE".

If I replace above data source settings in application.properties to use H2 database instead, all is working fine.  So, I know my java classes etc are all working fine but I am not sure what to do to resolve this issue and read data from a DB2 view.

Btw, since I am talking about database views here, my entity is annotated with @Immutable:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "CAR_VIEW") 
public class CarEntity implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```

As explained above, running this in H2 will create `CAR_VIEW` where I can use `CommandLineRunner` to prepopulate it with some data and then I can also query that data from Postman.

However, my DB2 database is already having this view and data provided by it (by joining few tables to get required data in the view).  So for DB2 database, I dont want JPA/Hibernate to create new `CAR_VIEW` (which is should not since I use `ddl-auto=update`), so it should see that the view already exist and I should be not getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I need to provide schema for my Entity class so once I added schema to the Table annotation, the issue has been resolved.

Compared to the above, my entity class is now having annotations as:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "CAR_VIEW", schema = "MY_SCHEMA") 
public class CarEntity implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```